# Python/Selenium - How to parse the URL and click next page?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to parse the hrefs and the titles of all articles from https://www.weforum.org/agenda/archive/covid-19 but I also want to pull information on the next page.

My code can only pull the current page but is not working on click() next page.

```
driver.get("https://www.weforum.org/agenda/archive/covid-19")

links =[]
titles = []

while True:
    for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tout__link'))):
        links.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
        titles.append(elem.text)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination__nav-text"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
    except:
        break
```

Can anyone help me with the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Try this `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[rel='next']"))).click()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class name 'pagination__nav-text' is not unique. As per the design, it clicks on the first found element which is "Prev" link. so you would not see that working.

Can you try with this approach,

```
    driver.get("https://www.weforum.org/agenda/archive/covid-19")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

links =[]
titles = []

while True:
    for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tout__link'))):
        links.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
        titles.append(elem.text)
    try:
        print('trying to click next')
        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='pagination__nav-text' and contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
    except:
        break


print(links)   
print(titles)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi Sureshmani, I tried the above xpath but it didn't click the next page.

Comment: see updated working code. I did it run it locally and seems to click the next button without issues.

Comment: Cool. The block of code works perfectly! Thank you for the help!